# How to do mouse hovering for group of buttons in python

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am just trying a mouse hovering function for a group of 5 buttons, mouse hovering color
setting is running fine with one button sample but it is not giving proper result 
when I tried for multiple buttons, it is affecting only last binded button, can anyone
help me quick on what is wrong with my below code,  I tried with bind and bind_all methods!
both are failing to give desired output.

```
import os
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
global btnPlaceY
btnPlaceY=10

class App():

    def __init__ (self):

        root['width']=400
        root['height']=600
        root['bg']='blue'
        self.btnGroupCreate()

    def btnDisplaymessage1(self):

        print "Function testing1"

    def btnDisplaymessage2(self):

        print "Function testing2"

    def btnGroupCreate(self):

        btnNameNameGroup="btnSample"
        self.btnWidget={}

        lstBtnTitle=['A','B','C','D','E']

        lstBtnCommands=[ lambda:self.btnDisplaymessage1(),
                         lambda:self.btnDisplaymessage2() ]

        for B in range(5):

            btnName=btnNameNameGroup+lstBtnTitle[B]  
            global btnPlaceY                
            btnPlaceY=btnPlaceY+70                  

            # Button commands
            if B==0:
                btnMenuCommand=lstBtnCommands[0]                    
            if B==1:
                btnMenuCommand=lstBtnCommands[1]
            if B==2:
                btnMenuCommand=lstBtnCommands[0]                    
            if B==3:
                btnMenuCommand=lstBtnCommands[1]                 

            if B==4:
                btnMenuCommand=lstBtnCommands[1] 
            if B==5:
                btnMenuCommand=lstBtnCommands[0]

            self.btnWidget[btnName]= tk.Button(root, width=4, height=2,text=lstBtnTitle[B],bg="gray",relief=FLAT,command=btnMenuCommand) #activebackground="red"
            widget = self.btnWidget[btnName]
            widget.bind_all("<Enter>", lambda event: event.widget.configure(bg="red"))
            widget.bind_all("<Leave>", lambda event: event.widget.configure(bg="gray"))
            self.btnWidget[btnName].pack()          
            self.btnWidget[btnName].place(x=40, y = btnPlaceY)

    def make_callback(self,btnName):
        print "make_callback"
        root['bg']='green'
        widget = self.btnWidget[btnName]
        def callback(event):
            print "callback"
            widget.configure(bg="red")
            root['bg']='green'
        return callback

root=tk.Tk()
app = App()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This isn't directly related to your problem, but your `if B==5:` code will never execute. With a range of 5, B will only ever have the values 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in Python the closures such as your lambda function, close over the names in the surrounding block, not the values. As such, the value of `btnName` as observed in the lambda depends on when it is executed - as the events can occur only after the loop is exited, the `btnName` is the last one seen.

There are many ways to avoid this problem, one being the Kevin's default value trick. However, the default value approach is prone to errors - now the function accepts 2 arguments instead of 1 and can be called erroneously in some context.

Thus a better approach is to use a callback maker:

```
def make_callback(btnName):
    def callback(event):
        self.btnWidget[btnName].configure(bg="red"))
    return callback

self.btnWidget[btnName].bind_all("<Enter>", make_callback(btnName))
```

However, one notices that the `btnWidget` is repeated, so it is possible to do this into

```
widget = self.btnWidget[btnName]

def make_callback(btnName):
    def callback(event):
        widget.configure(bg="red")
    return callback

widget.bind_all("<Enter>", make_callback(widget))
```

Which could be written with lambdas as:

```
widget = self.btnWidget[btnName]
widget.bind_all("<Enter>", 
    (lambda widget: lambda event: widget.configure(bg="red"))(widget))
```

---

However, in this case none of this trickery is necessary as the only thing needed in callback is the widget on which the event occurs. And that is readily available in the TkInter events in the attribute `widget`, so really all you need to do is

```
widget = self.btnWidget[btnName]
widget.bind_all("<Enter>", lambda event: event.widget.configure(bg="red"))
widget.bind_all("<Leave>", lambda event: event.widget.configure(bg="yellow"))
```

Comment: @ Antti and  Kevin, Appreciate you both for helping me and it is quite useful. Yesterday I spent lot of time, but I never understood why my whole window color is changing to red (I mean "root" color) and if I add more frame and other widgets the the whole program will become error prone! the color affects everything. My intention is that the color should affect only to the mouse pointing button not surrounding widgets!
Until I find the code in that level it is complex! I edited the code in my question with changes as you said, could you both please can have a look and help me?

Comment: @JohnR, I've updated my answer. I didn't notice initially that you were using `bind_all`, which should only be used for application level events such as keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.btnWidget[btnName].bind_all("<Enter>", lambda event:  self.btnWidget[btnName].configure(bg="red")) 
self.btnWidget[btnName].bind_all("<Leave>", lambda event:  self.btnWidget[btnName].configure(bg="yellow"))
```

Inside the lambda expressions on each of these lines, `btnName` will have the *last* value that it held during the loop, rather than the value it had when you bound the event. It will be "btnSampleE", even for buttons A through D. Additionally, you should be using `bind` instead of `bind_all` for widget-specific events.

The typical way to force "early binding" behavior, so that `btnName` keeps its current value, is to supply a default argument to the lambda, containing the value you need.

```
self.btnWidget[btnName].bind("<Enter>", lambda event, x = btnName: self.btnWidget[x].configure(bg="red")) 
self.btnWidget[btnName].bind("<Leave>", lambda event, x = btnName: self.btnWidget[x].configure(bg="yellow"))
```

You can use whatever variable name you want for this argument; you could even call it `btnName`, as the local value will overshadow the nonlocal one.

```
self.btnWidget[btnName].bind("<Enter>", lambda event, btnName=btnName:  self.btnWidget[btnName].configure(bg="red")) 
self.btnWidget[btnName].bind("<Leave>", lambda event, btnName=btnName:  self.btnWidget[btnName].configure(bg="yellow"))
```

Comment: Yes now it works fine, only pointing button highlighting! bind method is suitable to my program not bind_all! great help thanks a lot dude!